# Mysql Work bench : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I forgot my password. And while i am trying to connect to MySql its throwing an error

[image]

I have tried this but i am not able to login with same password in my Work bench

[image]

Comment: How about a simple search about `mysql forgot password`?

Comment: Yeah I have been searching since half an hour all are giving some commands but donno where exactly the commands need to be executed

Comment: Have you followed all aspects of [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html)